# Can the Gerrit login page be replaced？

Tags: gerrit

I want to edit the gerrit login page or add the background image myself.Who can tell me how to set it.
Thanks

I didn't find a solution online.I use ldap for authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this in the past. You need to add a custom css file, named GerritSite.css, to your etc folder.
I have uploaded my version as a gist, see https://gist.github.com/uncletall/5fb0cf342cf358fa67f53c1851587aa1

My images are in the static folder and you will need to change lines 46 and 47 is for the logo:

```
background-image: url(/r/static/your_logo.png);
background-image: linear-gradient(transparent,transparent), url(/r/static/your_logo.png);
```

and line 223 is the background image:

```
background-image: url(/r/static/your_image.jpg) !important;
```

To be honest, I have done this a while back so I can't remember the exact details of this.

You also need to add a LoginForm.html in the etc folder, see in this gist: https://gist.github.com/uncletall/d216e76c81fa861fb8583137efa71d69